# property="fb:admins" not working

Tags: html, facebook, plugins

I have added a Facebook comment box to a website i am making. However when i set the moderator of the comment box the moderator option is not available. Here is the code from the page.

```
*<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--
Template Name: PhotoBusiness
Author: <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/">OS Templates</a>
Author URI: http://www.os-templates.com/
Licence: Free to use under our free template licence terms
Licence URI: http://www.os-templates.com/template-terms
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Peakapot Photography</title>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="myNumericId"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/gallery/home/camera.ico" type="image/ico">

</head>
<body id="top">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="wrapper col1">
  <div id="topbar">
    <div id="search">
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Site Search</legend>
          <input type="text" value="Search the site&hellip;"  onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Search the site&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
          <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="GO" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col2">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1><a href="index.html">Peakapot Photography</a></h1>
      <p>Professional Photographer</p>
    </div>
    <ul id="topnav">
    <li class="active" class="last"><a href="comment.html">Comments</a></li>
    <li  class="last"><a href="buy.html">Photos for sale</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galleries</a>
        <ul>
          <li ><a href="family.html">Family</a></li>
          <li><a href="booth.html">Photo Booth</a></li>
          <li><a href="cake.html">Cake Smash</a></li>
          <li><a href="Baby.html">Baby</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
      <li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col3">
<!--</div>-->
<br class="clear" />
</br>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Comments</h2>

    <br>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:8000/photodemo/price.html" data-colorscheme="dark" data-width="950" data-numposts="10"></div>    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
<!--<div class="wrapper col4">-->
  <div id="services">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Family</strong><img src="images/gallery/home/homefamily.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Baby</strong><img src="images/gallery/home/homebaby.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Cake Smash</strong><img src="images/gallery/home/homecake.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#"><strong>Boudoir</strong><img src="images/gallery/booth/boothhome.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
<!--</div>-->
<div class="wrapper col5">

</div>
<div class="wrapper col6">
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="contactform">
      <h2>Why Not Contact Us Today</h2>
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Contact Form</legend>
          <label for="fullname">Name:
            <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" value="" />
          </label>
          <label for="emailaddress" class="margin">Email:
            <input id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" type="text" value="" />
          </label>
          <label for="message">Message:<br />
            <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
          </label>
          <p>
            <input id="submitform" name="submitform" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            &nbsp;
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End Contact Form -->
    <div id="compdetails">
      <div id="officialdetails">
        <h2>Company Information</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Copyright &copy; 2016 - All Rights Reserved</li>
          <li>Peakapot Photography</li>
          <li>Sole Trader</li>
          <li>Fully Insured</li>
          <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="contactdetails">
        <h2>Our Contact Details</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Peakapot Photography</li>
          <li>22 Fallowfield Road</li>
          <li>Colchester</li>
          <li>CO2 9ND</li>
          <li>Tel: 07493097053</li>
          <li>Email: daniel@peakapot.com</li>
        <!--  <li class="last">LinkedIn: <a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>-->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col7">
  <div id="copyright">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Online Privacy Policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Permissions &amp; Trademarks</a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#">Product License Agreements</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>*
```

In order to help you out with fault finding i have hosted a live version at http://photography.peakapot.com/comment.html with the correct updated comment code. If anyone can tell me why this moderator feature is not available to me i would greatly appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Regards Peakapot

Comment: I'm just commenting to bump the question.

Comment: If you go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments can you see any options there?